# How to move expandible list dynamically

Tags: android

How can a `ExpandibleList` be moved to a particular index dynamically in **Android**. e.g. there are 100 groups in `ExpandibleList` and on some menu click I want the list to move from index 0 to index 50.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
exList.setSelectedGroup(groupPosition);
```